# Is doing a PhD just for the university requirement is a good idea?

Tags: phd, job, university

I have an MSc degree and I work at university as a lecturer. However, the university has a  policy where you should do your PhD within a given time frame. The problem is that I'm not interested in any area yet, nor am I interested in doing the work associated with a PhD.

Should I just go with it because the university forces me to do it, or should I just quit from the university and look for another job?

What do you think? Can I succeed if I start doing my PhD while i feel that I'm forced to do it?

Comment: If you don't really enjoy research, it's not a good idea to get a PhD.

Comment: _nor I'm interested in doing hard work_ — Um.  No, you don't want a PhD.  And you probably don't want to be a lecturer either.

Comment: @JeffE : And I wouldn't want this person as my lecturer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my university back in Mexico, they had something similar, if professors want to get ahead (income, professional, etc) they had to an additional degree (Masters, PhD)

I think that if you do not have the motivation, you'll have a lot of problems, doing a PhD is already a taxing endeavor, in the sense that many times you'll start wondering wether this was a good idea or not.

As in many things in life, if you do this because you are made to (like students that go to college because their parents want to) you'll have lots of resentment.

However, not all is lost, you can try looking for something you are really passionate about, and then try to do a PhD on that.

Answer (score 5):

A PhD has the potential to open many doors. Its better to do it when there is some motivation than regret later. Think six years from now and where you want to be and whether it would require a PhD.

Do note that it is not easy. It requires hardwork and dedication. There would be many times when you would want to quit. So have a strong reason to pull you through when this happens.

Most importantly, in my view you would be better placed in whatever field you choose with a PhD. You may be afraid of sacrificing three years of your life now but what about the rest of the years ahead. As the say, time flies. Only you can make the call.

Answer (score 4):

Above all, a PhD is about learning how to become a researcher. You mention that you have a lecturer position, does it include doing research? If you want to become a researcher in addition to teaching, a PhD is the way to go. If performing research is what you want, doing a PhD is logical, and should be worth it. If you have no ambition in being a researcher, a PhD is going to be a very painful process, similar to doing any other job you do not enjoy.

In the end, it is all about what you want. If you want to be a reseacher, do a PhD. If not, I would not recommend it.